# serving media in django

Tags: python, django, django-templates

I was going through serving media in django and the I encountered a project with this line of code

```
href="{{STATIC_URL}}/custom/js/list.js"
```

in settings, STATIC_URL= /xexo/static/. That means the url will become

```
127.0.0.1:8000/xexo/static//custom/js/list.js
```

notice the //. Surprisingly even if I do this

```
127.0.0.1:8000/xexo/static///////custom/js/list.js 
or 
127.0.0.1:8000/xexo/static/////custom/////js/list.js
```

in my browser, the list.js will still load. 
My qn is, how is this possible?

EDIT

Here is another link I have found

[Link 1](http://powerful-earth-4121.herokuapp.com/AuShadha/static/////plugins/dojo-1.8.0/dijit/themes/claro/claro.css)

[Link 2](http://powerful-earth-4121.herokuapp.com/AuShadha/static/////plugins/////dojo-1.8.0////////dijit/themes/claro/claro.css)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This questions url is:

`http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15260904/serving-media-in-django`

I can add a few slashes in and it works fine...

`http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15260904///////serving-media-in-django`

My point being this isn't a *thing* associated with serving media in django, this seems to be typical browser behaviour.

Answer (score 0):

Although it doesn't seem to cause any problems in the browser to have multiple slashes it might be best to avoid it and change that line to:

```
href="{{STATIC_URL}}custom/js/list.js"
```

so the double slash is avoided.